# How does implicit casting work in Oracle NoSQL Database?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I am trying to understand the implicit cast behavior.
I have a column called ticketNo, this is a string and it is a pk.
Using the same datatype in both sides, I am returning one row

```
SELECT * FROM demo d  WHERE ticketNo = "1762386738153"
```

When I am doing a explicit cast, this query is returning the same row

```
SELECT * FROM demo d  WHERE cast (ticketNo as Long)= 1762386738153
```

Now, when I am doing an implicit cast, this query is returning no rows

```
SELECT * FROM demo d  WHERE ticketNo = 1762386738153
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **implicit cast** behavior in Oracle NoSQL Database. String types are not comparable to Long types so the predicate `ticketNo = 1762386738153` returns always false in your case. A string item is comparable to another string item. A string item is also comparable to an enum item.

In your case, this is your primary key, in order to have the best performances, it is not recommended to do a CAST. Validate the types before do this query. A primary key is always typed, no wildcard or complex types are accepted

Otherwise,

> the reason for returning false for incomparable items, instead of
> raising an error, is to handle truly schemaless applications, where
> different table rows may contain very different data or differently
> shaped data. As a result, even the writer of the query may not know
> what kind of items an operand may return and an operand may indeed
> return different kinds of items from different rows.

you can always execute the explicit CAST operation when needed, as you did.

If you are interested in have more information : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/20.3/sqlreferencefornosql/value-comparison-operators.html